# Twilio with Capybara Getting "stack level too deep (SystemStackError)" error

Tags: ruby, twilio, capybara

I am getting `stack level too deep (SystemStackError)` error when trying to make `Read: List messages matching filter criteria` API call for Twilio in Selenium/Cucumber framework.
I have no issues making this API call outside of Capybara framework as a pure Ruby code.

Here is my code:

```
@mfa_client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token
@mfa_client.messages.list(from: "+#{@sender_phone}", to: "+#{@recipient_phone}", limit: 1)

Error:

/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/capybara-3.37.1/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:46:in `page': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
        from /.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/capybara-3.37.1/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:52:in `query'
        from /.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/capybara-3.37.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:771:in `query'
        from /.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/capybara-3.37.1/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:52:in `call'
        from /.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/capybara-3.37.1/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:52:in `query'
        from /.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/capybara-3.37.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:771:in `query'
        from /.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/capybara-3.37.1/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:52:in `call'
        from /.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/capybara-3.37.1/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:52:in `query'
        from /.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/capybara-3.37.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:771:in `query'
         ... 10607 levels...
        from /.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/bin/spinach:23:in `load'
        from /.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/bin/spinach:23:in `<main>'
        from /.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
        from /.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Try Capybara 3.36.x just to make sure it’s not a bug introduced in 3.37. Beyond that the twillio client isn’t what’s calling Capybara, so you need to look through the full backtrack and see what Capybara command is being called before it goes into a recursive loop

Comment: Thanks! 
I will try. 
To confirm. Yes, this is not an issue with Twilio. This looks like an issue with Capybara/Cucumber framework.

Comment: You should also update your question to show the code where the error is coming from - ie the code that's actually calling Capybara.

Comment: Here is what I found in regards of Capybara code/framework:

    def current_session
      specified_session || session_pool["#{current_driver}:#{session_name}:#{app.object_id}"]
    end

Comment: `current_session` doesn't call `query` -- Can you provide the whole (non-redacted) stack trace for the error?